# Is it possible to NOT INCLUDE the import statement and still let it compile itself? (Scanner)

Tags: java, import

Is it possible to NOT INCLUDE the import statement and still let it compile itself?

Example:

```
class test
{
    public static void main(String args)
    {
         Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    }
}
```

Comment: `java.util.Scanner scn = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);`

Answer (score 1):

Sure, by using the fully qualified name `java.util.Scanner` everywhere. Usually you'd do that only to distinguish two classes with the same name.

Comment: Thanks, does that apply to all java-classes?

Comment: Yes. Note that it doesn't make sense to avoid importing. There's no performance benefits or any reason not to use `import java.util.*;` and then just happily write `Scanner` instead of `java.util.Scanner`.